# Incompatible type from typedef defined pointer in c

Tags: c, warnings

Using VS 2019, the following C code function is giving me C4133 warning as well as several other area's throughout my code. The warning states:
 "Warning C4133 '=': incompatible types - from 'client *' to 'client_t"

However, from my typedef client* and client_t should be the same thing unless I misunderstand the syntax for typdef. Below is one instance where I get this warning:

```
//Client information structure for linked list
typedef struct _client {
    char NAME[30];
    unsigned long PHONE;
    unsigned long ID;
    unsigned char CountryID;
    struct client *next;
    struct client *previous;
}client, *client_t;

/*Function to sequentually free every node in the doubly linked list
@param: client_t *head - reference pointer to the head pointer of the client linked list
*/
void RemoveClient(client_t *head) {
    if (head)
    {
        client_t current = *head;

        if (current && current->next) {
            while (current) {
                //Warning C4133 at the below line
                current = (*head)->next;
                free(*head);
                *head = current;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free(*head);
        }
        current = NULL;
        *head = NULL;
    }
    else printf("head is a NULL pointer");
}
```

Comment: *Below is one instance where I get this warning* – where? Which line #? Better: mark the occurrence of the warning in your code.

Comment: @Swordfish: He did.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten an underscore on the type for next and previous.  The `struct` is `_client`...

Comment: I'll make the line in question stand out more but i'm not sure with how the formatting for code blocks works, if anyone has a suggestion i'd appreciate it. @cyberbisson You might be right and i'll go and change that and see if it makes a difference, other than the warning my program functions fine though.

Comment: @cremno Oh, he died!?

Comment: @ZacharyMartin I'll just go ahead and write an explanation as to what went wrong, now that we know that fixes the problem -- cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happened is you're referencing a *forward declared* type that does not exist, named `struct client`:

```c
//Client information structure for linked list
typedef struct _client {
    // ...
    struct client *next;
    struct client *previous;
}client, *client_t;
```

This is a bit tricky.  At the time of your declarations of `next` and `previous`, you have a type named `struct _client`.  Shortly thereafter, you have a `typedef` named `client`.  Neither of those are `struct client`, unfortunately.  Since the operations are only referencing the pointer, but not de-referencing them, you don't have any actual errors, but when you refer to `next`, the compiler says "huh, `struct client` is neither `client` nor `struct _client` -- be wary!"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cyberbission for your suggestion! Changing my components inside of the struct to _client instead of using the later given definition of client fixed alot of those warnings for me:

```
//Client information structure for linked list
typedef struct _client {
    char NAME[30];
    unsigned long PHONE;
    unsigned long ID;
    unsigned char CountryID;
    struct _client *next;
    struct _client *previous;
}client, *client_t;
```